# how do we know which interface to use?

Tags: android

i can't understand how we know what to use inside these onclick or onchange listeners in android. i'm kind of a newbie so would appreciate an indetail explanation.

```
 //Example 1
 mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                mTrueButton.setEnabled(!mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswered());
                mFalseButton.setEnabled(!mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswered());
                checkAnswer(true);
                mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].setAnswered(true);
                mTrueButton.setEnabled(!mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswered());
                mFalseButton.setEnabled(!mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswered());


        }
    });


    // Example 2
    mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

In the examples above we use "new View.onClickListener()" and "new TextWatcher()".... but how do i know as a beginner which interface to implement?

Answer (score 0):

check for the parameter that a function expects, and pass the interface accordingly, you can check what interface a function is expecting by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>